# Xamarin enabled GPS android / IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Good afternoon,

How do I turn on GPS in android and IOS project after giving consent?

The consent code works seamlessly:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += Current_ConnectivityChanged;
        CheckPermissions();

    }

    private async void CheckPermissions()
    {
        var status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();

        if(status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            return; 
        }
        else
        {
            await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();
        }

    }
```

How do I turn on the GPS automatically after giving consent?

Comment: Once access is granted your app has access to the GPS.  You can start using it.  However, this plugin has been deprecated in favor of Xamarin Essentials

Comment: I understand that but how do I turn on the GPS?

Comment: You don't turn it on.  You have no control over whether it is on or not.  Read the docs on the plugin for how to use it once access is granted